# Which type of LED for digital communication for a few hundred feet?

Tags: led

My latest hare-brained idea is to communicate between my barn to my house using an LED transmitter. The barn is perhaps 200' from the house, max. I'd be transmitting binary data, not analog, so a rapid off-on-off cycle time would be preferred.

Which type of LED? I don't know if common LEDs phosphors that make the light linger or not. If so, those would likely not be the best choice.  What frequency could I expect to get out of it?

Comment: Laser..................

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://hackaday.com/2017/04/19/go-wireless-with-this-diy-laser-ethernet-link/

Comment: agree.... laser

Comment: 200 ft with line of sight would work well using regular wifi and a directional antenna.  If you want to go optical and build something for fun at that distance, you'd need some optics to make an LED work. Laser will save you some effort on the lenses.

Comment: Do you ever get rain, snow, mist, or fog?

Comment: @Jasen Of course. It won't work then. Sort of like Dish TV :-D

Comment: Over 200 feet you'd have to align the laser pretty accurately. Or use a large area photocell. You can get 6x6 inch ones, but I have no idea what sort of bandwidth you get from them...